# Deserializing XML gives me null instead of the object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE paymentService PUBLIC "-//WorldPay//DTD WorldPay PaymentService v1//EN"
                                "http://dtd.worldpay.com/paymentService_v1.dtd">
<paymentService version="1.4" merchantCode="ABC">
    <reply>
        <error code="4">
            <![CDATA[Security violation]]>
        </error>
    </reply>
</paymentService>
```

I'm deserializing it into classes created using the XSD they provided:

```
var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "paymentService";

XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(paymentService), xRoot);

var someResponse = (paymentService) mySerializer.Deserialize(responseStreamReader);
```

It deserializes the paymentService, version, merchantCode, but the `Item` property is `null`.

This is part of the schema:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/worldpa
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/worldpay", IsNullable = false
public partial class paymentService
{

    private object itemField;

    private paymentServiceVersion versionField;

    private string merchantCodeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("inquiry", typeof (inquiry))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("modify", typeof (modify))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("notify", typeof (notify))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("reply", typeof (reply))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("submit", typeof (submit))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("verify", typeof (verify))]
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemField; }
        set { this.itemField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
    public paymentServiceVersion version
    {
        get { return this.versionField; }
        set { this.versionField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string merchantCode
    {
        get { return this.merchantCodeField; }
        set { this.merchantCodeField = value; }
    }
}
```

I would expect the Item to be a `reply` object.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: That class looks like the data that should be returned on a successful call whereas the XML you posted looks to be an error of some sort. You could perhaps add the `reply` property to `paymentService`?

Comment: The `paymentService` class has an  `object Item` field that can be anything declared in the attributes above, one of which is `typeof(reply)`, so I would expect it to work.

Comment: What happens if you remove `XmlTypeAttribute` and `XmlRootAttribute` from the `paymentService` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this, possibly not in the best way, but for the benefit of others..

I just removed the namespaces from everything.

My schema was generated with XSD.exe and I removed all references to `Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/worldpay"`, and this fixed it. It also meant I didn't have to mess around with the XmlRootAttribute.